# How to upload an image file directly from client to AWS S3 using node, createPresignedPost, & fetch

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, fetch

I'm generating an AWS S3 presigned post object on my server using `s3.createPresignedPost()`. I'm then trying to upload a file directly to the S3 bucket from the client using fetch using the presigned post url & fields, but am getting a `403 Forbidden`.

I've tried manually adding form fields to my FormData object to directly match this example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html but continue to receive the 403 error.

Server-side function for generating the post object

```
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk/global");
    const S3 = require("aws-sdk/clients/s3");
    const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");

    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: process.env.S3_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY,
      region: "us-east-1"
    });

    const s3 = new S3();

    const getPresignedPostData = (bucket, directory) => {
      const key = `${directory}/${uuidv4()}`;
      const postData = s3.createPresignedPost({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Fields: { Key: key, success_action_status: "201" },
        Conditions: [{ acl: "public-read" }],
        ContentType: "image/*",
        Expires: 300
      });
      return postData;
    };
```

Returns something that looks like:

```
    {
      fields: {
        Key: "5cd880a7f8b0480b11b9940c/86d5552b-b713-4023-9363-a9b36130a03f"
        Policy: {Base64-encoded policy string}
        X-Amz-Algorithm: "AWS-HMAC-SHA256"
        X-Amz-Credential: "AKIAI4ELUSI2XMHFKZOQ/20190524/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"
        X-Amz-Date: "20190524T200217Z"
        X-Amz-Signature: "2931634e9afd76d0a50908538798b9c103e6adf067ba4e60b5b54f90cda49ce3"
        bucket: "picture-perfect-photos"
        success_action_status: "201"
      },
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/picture-perfect-photos"
    }
```

My client side function looks like:

```
    const uploadToS3 = async ({ fields, url }, file) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        Object.keys(fields).forEach(key => formData.append(key, fields[key]));
        formData.append("file", file);

        try {
          const config = {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
          };
          const response = await fetch(url, config);

          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
          }

          const data = await response.json();
          return data;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      };
```

And my S3 bucket CORS config is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
    </CORSConfiguration>
```

I expect to get the XML document that is sent when `success_action_status: "201"` is set, but am continually getting `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Does the user have proper access to the bucket? Does the s3 policy have any restrictions?

Comment: The user authenticated on the server side has access. I was able to properly post files from the server.

For more info, the public access is as follows:
Block all public access: **Off**
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs): **Off**
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs): **Off**
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket policies: **On**
Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket policies: **On**

Comment: @Jonathan did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The only other answer on this thread is talking about totally different S3 API call.

There are 2 similar but different APIs:

- getSignedUrl
- createPresignedPost

I myself needed `createPresignedPost` and was using `getSignedUrl` before because i want to limit the file size which can be uploaded to much less then what AWS S3 supports. In my case I let users to upload images. Up to 10MB in size. While upload coming from client side I need way to limit file upload size. If you google around this situation, people suggest to delete already uploaded big files, but i don't like letting to upload to begin with.

So, while using the actual `createPresignedPost` API call you get back not only the `url` but `fields` too.

Fields is object with key-value pairs.

**On client side you need:**

Send POST request to the url (`getSignedUrl` is requiring PUT instead) and all the fields you got you must provide as form's fields. Only extra form field is called `file` and that's where you put your file you upload.

Here is sample PostMan screenshot with all form filed up:

[image]